# "The method generate(Supplier<? extends T>) in the type Stream is not applicable for the arguments (int)" with List = Stream.generate()

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I am trying to generate a random list of integers like the following:

```
private static int nextElement() {
    Random r = new Random();
    return r.nextInt(100);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] integers = Stream.generate(nextElement())
                            .limit(200)
                            .toArray(Integer[]::new);
}
```

The error, manifested as a red squigly under `generate`, states the following:

```
The method generate(Supplier<? extends T>) in the type Stream is not 
 applicable for the arguments (int)
```

I think this means that the *return* type for `nextElement()` must not be an `int`, but I may be wrong. How can I fix this code, so that a random list of integers can be generated?

Answer (score 5):

When you call `nextElement()`, you get an `int`. But `generate` wants a `Supplier<T>`. A *supplier* will be called by `generate`, it's not meant for you to invoke. So:

```
Stream.generate(YourClass::nextElement).limit(200).toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

or

```
Stream.generate(() -> nextElement()).limit(200).toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

---

Note that your code can be improved by avoiding the boxed integers if you use `IntStream`:

```
int[] integers = IntStream.generate(YourClass::nextElement).limit(200).toArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

The `Stream#generate(Supplier)` method accepts a `Supplier` argument. However, you are passing the result of calling `#nextElement()` directly, which is an `int`. The simple fix is to use:

```java
Stream.generate(() -> nextElement())...
```

The `() -> nextElement()` is a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and is an implementation of `Supplier<Integer>`. It could also be written as a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html): `EnclosingClass::nextElement`.

---

That being said, there is a simpler way to generate a stream of random numbers using [`Random#ints(long,int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#ints(long,int,int)), which:

> Returns a stream producing the given streamSize number of pseudorandom int values, each conforming to the given origin (inclusive) and bound (exclusive).

Here's an example that will generate 200 random numbers in the range [0,100):

```java
int[] array = new Random().ints(200, 0, 100).toArray();
```

The above also has the benefit of using an `IntStream` which lets you use `int` instead of `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you need to pass a function!

Not a value )

generate method receives a function

This will work

```
Stream.generate(() -> {return nextElement();})
```

This wont

```
Stream.generate(nextElement())
```

Java's Stream belongs to Functional Paradigm, where most of time you pass functions as arguments, -not objects-.